# Filling matrix with numbers in a specific way in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, element, fill

I have a program, where I have to print a matrix, for example for n=5 (the user can enter any  positive integer n<20 ), in this way:

```
0 20 19 17 14
1 0 18 16  13
2 5 0  15  12
3 6 8  0   11
4 7 9  10   0
```

My initial idea was to fill the main diagonal with zeroes and than from 1 to `(n*n-n)/2` to fill the matrix with these elements under the main diagonal `(i>j)`, and from `(n*n-n)/2` up to n -  the elements above the main diagonal `(i<j)`. However, the program does not work as expected. I would like to ask why this happens.

Comment: You are declaring `i` multiple times (in the outermost loop and in the two innermost loops). It's not forbidden, but it's probably not doing what you think.

Comment: Removing the code in a why does my program not work question is an unusual choice and makes the question unanswerable.

Comment: Post the whole code... I'm running in "Confusion" mode right-now.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from multiple declaration of **i** and **a**, your loops keep assigning values to the same variable.

```
// changed i to k because of double declaration
for(int k=1; k<(n*n-n)/2; k++)
{
    a[i][j]=k;
}
```

Better way of doing this would be:

```
int number = 1;
int col = 0, row = 1;
while(col < n && row < n){
    for(int pos = row; pos < n; ++pos){
        mat[col][pos] = number++;
    }
    ++col;++row;
}

col = n-1;
row = n-2;
while(col >= 0 && row >= 0){
    for(int pos = row; pos >= 0; --pos){
        mat[col][pos] = number++;
    }
    --col;--row;
}
```